# Rotating matrix 90 degrees left side in c++ example code

Tags: matrix

I tried using this code but I'm unable to get the required output. I gave a 3*3 matrix as input
1 2 3|4 5 6| 7 8 9 and resultant matrix expected is 7 4 1 | 8 5 6 | 9 6 3 .

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int size;
cin>>size;
int matrix[size][size];
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
        cin>>matrix[i][j];
    }
}
cout<<"Original Matrix"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
        cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
cout<<"After left rotating"<<endl;
int tempMatrix[size][size];
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
        tempMatrix[i][j]=matrix[j][i];
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
        cout<<tempMatrix[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        int size;
        cin>>size;
        int matrix[size][size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                cin>>matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout<<"Original Matrix"<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"After left rotating"<<endl;
        int tempMatrix[size][size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                tempMatrix[i][j]=matrix[size-j-1][i];
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                cout<<tempMatrix[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Hope this works.
Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).